# Overriding a javascript method

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new to OOP in javascript. I can't get it right when I want to override a method. I made an example of my problem below. Also in http://jsfiddle.net/sRyQA/

```
function myGeometryObject(r, x, y){

    this.r = r;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    var OBJ = this;

    this.returnArea = function(){
        return 'wrong override';
    }
}

function myRectangle(r, x, y){
    myGeometryObject.call(this, r, x, y);
}
myRectangle.prototype = new myGeometryObject();

myRectangle.prototype.returnArea = function(){
    return 'right override';//I want JS to use this method
}
var rectangle = new myRectangle(0, 5, 5);
alert(rectangle.returnArea());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that

```
this.returnArea = function(){
    return 'wrong override';
}
```

will set the property of that particular **instance** (as you are *correctly* calling the parent's constructor on the new `MyRectangle` instance) , and this will "override" all inherited methods.

Your prototype chain looks like this:

```
 +------------------+        +------------------+        +------------------+
 | MyRectangle      |        | MyRectangle      |        | MyGeometry       |
 | instance         |------->| prototype        |------->| prototype        |
 |                  |        |                  |        |                  |
 | wrong returnArea |        | right returnArea |        |                  |
 +------------------+        +------------------+        +------------------+
                             (MyGeometry instance)
```

where the `retunArea` method at the instance is the one you assign in the `MyGeometryObject` constructor and the one of the prototype is the one you have overwritten.

But if you assign this method to `MyGeometryObject`'s `prototype`

```
function MyGeometryObject(r, x, y) { 
    this.r = r;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
}

MyGeometryObject.prototype.returnArea = function(){
    return 'wrong override';
}
```

then it will work, as the right `returnArea` method will come earlier in the prototype chain:

```
 +------------------+        +------------------+        +------------------+
 | MyRectangle      |        | MyRectangle      |        | MyGeometry       |
 | instance         |------->| prototype        |------->| prototype        |
 |                  |        |                  |        |                  |
 |                  |        | right returnArea |        | wrong returnArea |
 +------------------+        +------------------+        +------------------+
                             (MyGeometry instance)
```

**Further notes:**

- Constructor function names should start with a capital letter.
- If you set the prototype of `MyRectangle` this way, you should also set the `constructor` property back to `MyRectangle`:

  ```
  MyRectangle.prototype = new MyGeometryObject();
  MyRectangle.prototype.constructor = MyRectangle;
  ```

Comment: Another way is to overwrite the method in the `myRectangle` constructor (after applying the arguments to the `myGeometryObject` constructor). http://jsfiddle.net/sRyQA/2/

Comment: @Felix KLing What does MyRectangle.prototype.constructor = MyRectangle do?

Comment: @Woho87: It sets the `constructor` property of the prototype to `MyRectangle`. This property always points the the function the prototype is the prototype of. Try: `function Foo(){}; console.dir(Foo.protoype);`.

Comment: @Woho87, it makes sure, that when calling new myRectagle, the correct constructor (therefor the myRectangle function, assigning the this.x, this.y etc.) will be called instead of the one of MyGeometryObject!